# Prevent Duplicate Hangfire Recurring Jobs from multiple web apps running off same database

Tags: c#, cron, hangfire, recurring

The creation of recurring jobs is done on our web app startup. 
We will sometimes run a beta version of our web app in a separate IIS website, but hitting the same database as our main production web app. When we do this, hangfire will re-create the jobs when we start the beta app, but those jobs already exists as they were created from the Prod app.

What is the best way to prevent the second instance of our web app from duplicating the recurring jobs?

I don't think I want to user `RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists` because if the job exists when originally added from Prod, then we fire up Beta, it will delete the job running under Prod. Then when we shut down beta, that job will no longer exists...at least until we recycle the Prod app.